Powershell script: result of New-LocalUser used in loop are cached and object displayed at end - want to suppress that output
I'm fairly new to writing Powershell scripts.  I have written one (using suggestions and templates from various web resources) and it is working rather well.  I am outputting my own results as the script goes along, to standard-out.  The script reads from a CSV file, tests and creates users; adds to a Group; reports results (each user on a single line, each stage's listed horizontally).
One issue, though:  If the process actually creates a new User, at the very end of the script it is spitting out the Users object of ALL the accounts that were created.  They aren't being sprinkled in during the processing - it waits until the very end and just returns the entire object of all users it created.  I'm not explicitly displaying the object.  I would like to suppress that final output.
Here's my PS code:
param(
    $FilePath
)

# Setup
$Count_Attempted = 0
$Count_Created = 0
$Count_MissingName =0
$Count_MissingPW = 0
$Count_MissingGroup = 0
$Count_Exists = 0

# Read the data
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path $FilePath

#  Initial header for the output:
Write-Host "  -------------    STARTED SCRIPT: $(Get-Date) ------------- `r`n"

# Loop through each row containing user details in the csv file
ForEach ($User in ($CSV))   {
    $Count_Attempted++

        #  REQUIRED items
    $Username     = $User.'UserName'
    $Password     = $User.'UserPassword'
    if ( $Password -ne "" ){
        $SecurePW  = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
    $Group        = $User.'Group'

        # Nice, but optional:
    $FirmName     = $User.'NameOfFirm'
    $FirmNumber   = $User.'VendorNumber'
    $Fullname  = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($User.'firstname'.ToLower()) + " " + (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($User.'lastname'.ToLower())
    $Description = "$FirmNumber|$FirmName"
    $Description = $Description.subString(0, [System.Math]::Min(48, $Description.Length))


        # -------------     Start-header for the output:
    write-host "$Username|$FullName`: " -NoNewline

    if  ( $Username -eq "" ) {
         write-host "Missing Username - skipping" -ForegroundColor Yellow
         $Count_MissingName++
    } elseif ( $Password -eq "" ) {
         write-host "Missing Password - skipping" -ForegroundColor Yellow
         $Count_MissingPW++
    } elseif (  $Group -eq ""  )  {
         write-host "Missing Group - skipping"  -ForegroundColor Yellow
         $Count_MissingGroup++

    } else {

        #  ============    1:  Check if the user account already exists
        $UserExists = get-localuser "$Username" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


        #  1a:  DOES  exist - skip it
        if ($UserExists -ne $null) {
            write-host "Account exists - skipping." -ForegroundColor Yellow
            $Count_Exists++
        }
        #  1b:  does NOT exist - create new one
        else{
            write-host " does not exist - creating: " -NoNewline
    
                # +++++++++++    2:  Create New Local User
            New-LocalUser -Name $Username  -Password $SecurePW  -FullName $Fullname -Description $Description -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -AccountNeverExpires
    
                #    2a:   Test result:  $? should be 'True' if it went OK, 'False' if it did not
            if ( $? -eq $true ) {
                Write-Host "Success;" -ForegroundColor Green  -NoNewline
                Write-Host "`tAdding to Group - $Group`:"  -NoNewline

                #  +++++++++   3:   Add user to their Group, too
                Add-LocalGroupMember -Group $Group -Member $Username

                if ($? -eq $true ) {
                    Write-Host " Success" -ForegroundColor Green
                    $Count_Created++
                } else {
                    Write-Host " FAILED!" -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
            else {
                Write-Host "FAILED!!" -ForegroundColor Red
            }

        }        #  <---  END of User=create attempt
    }       #  <---  END of User entry values are good
}       #  <---  END of FOR EACH loop - iterating over user entries in CSV


# Finish Commands
Write-Host "`n`nAttempted:   $Count_Attempted"
Write-Host "Created:     $Count_Created"
Write-Host "`tAlready exists:    $Count_Exists"
Write-Host "`tMissing Names:     $Count_MissingName"
Write-Host "`tMissing Password:  $Count_MissingPW"
Write-Host "`tMissing Group:     $Count_MissingGroup"
Write-Host "  -------------    ENDED SCRIPT: $(Get-Date) -------------" 

The output is:
1 - user_jAKn|Izzy Logan:    Missing Password - skipping
2 - user_iVam|Michael Hamen:     does not exist - creating: 
 Success;   Adding to Group - Vendor: Success
3 - user_hwdH|Pat Napolou:   does not exist - creating:  Success;   Adding to Group - Attorney: Success
4 - user_dcya|Susan Dennis:  does not exist - creating:  Success;   Adding to Group - Vendor: Success
5 - user_FFfn|Carl Black:    does not exist - creating:  Success;   Adding to Group - Vendor: Success

Attempted:   5
Created:     4
    Already exists:    0
    Missing Names:     0
    Missing Password:  1
    Missing Group:     0
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^    ENDED SCRIPT: 09/12/2024 14:55:17   ^^^^^^^^^^
Name      Enabled Description                                     
----      ------- -----------                                     
user_iVam True    |Premier Process Partners Of Pekipsy Pennsylvani
user_hwdH True    2001|Flynn And Candleman             
user_dcya True    14442|Yale University School Of Medicine Treasur
user_FFfn True    14442|Yale University School Of Medicine Treasur 

So I am not explicitly returning/outputting the object.  It just happens.  How can I suppress that output?

In short: any output - be it from a PowerShell command, an operator-based expression, or a .NET method call - that is neither captured in a variable nor redirected (sent to a file or via the pipeline to another command) is implicitly output from a script or function. To simply discard such output, use $null = ....
If you don't discard such output, it becomes part of a script or function's "return value" (stream of output objects), which is not limited to what is passed to an - optional - return statement.
See the linked duplicate for more information.

In short: $null = New-LocalUser .... As for why the user objects only printed after your Write-Host messages, see this answer.

Perfect!  I changed the 'New-LocalUser...' line to:  $MakeUser = New-LocalUser... and it behaving as you described, and as I wanted.  (It also seems to have rectified a weird line-wrapping issue I had.)  Hmmm... will it affect the error-trapping I'm doing with "$?" ?  Is that result now going to be the result of the command, or the result of the setting the variable to the output of the command?

No, whether or not you capture a command's output in a variable has no impact on $?.

I forced an error by providing a bad variable name.  Error trapping appears fine, but the output of the Command now shows in the middle of the run.  I was trying to suppress all output of the 'New-LocalUser...' with the "-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue" flag.  But I get this in my output now (1st half is my output, 2nd half of this line is command error, much truncated):  5 - user_FFfn|Carl Black:  does not exist - creating: New-LocalUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Password'...

(If you want to add your comments as an "Answer", then I can pick it as the solution.)

Your question is just about output suppression, so I think marking it as a duplicate is sufficient. It's unclear to me if you have still have a - different - problem after resolving the output-suppression one; if you do, I encourage you to create a new question post.

I don't think that it is 'different' in the end, no... but I'm not sure I would have understood what those other threads were discussing.  :)  Or would have thought they didn't apply in my situation because I wasn't (directly) trying to use a Format-Table.  (It's used in the result of the New-LocalUser output though - but I didn't know that.)  So your answer was a more direct fix for my situation.  Not sure the supporting 'original' answers you linked to ever described that as a way to get around the issue.  (But it did yield a new issue of errors showing up mid-stream.)

Oh holy pooh - I think I missed your linkage to another posting at the extreme top of the posting.  I was just reading through your comments and following those links.  The one you linked at the very top (above my own posting entirely) is more simplified and direct.  Sorry about that.

No worries - glad we're on the same page now.

Skimmed through the other threads, but not sure I saw insights about why the error output of the New-LocalUser command was now spitting out it's multi-lines of red text in the middle of the process.  (The successful run output I was seeing at the very end is now correctly suppressed, thanks to your tip.)  I am using the -ErrorAction silentlyContinue in the command itself - seems like the error text would be suppressed by that.

I have no explanation, but I encourage you to ask a new question focused just on your remaining problem.
